# Getting a null object reference on getting token from SharedPreferences using Retrofit2 GET request

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, retrofit2

I'm trying to get an access_token from my SharedPreferences to pass into the Body of a Retrofit2 GET request. When I login I get an access_token and save it in SharedPreferences, but when I try and get the value of the SharedPreference I get a null object reference error but I am unsure as to why.

The full error log can be found below:
**Logcat log**:

```
2020-08-27 10:23:29.597 2825-2974/com.example.dentdevils E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher
    Process: com.example.dentdevils, PID: 2825
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.example.dentdevils.helper.retrofit.oauth2.PreferenceClass.getToken()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.dentdevils.helper.retrofit.oauth2.client.cCustomerService$1.intercept(cCustomerService.java:41)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:229)
        at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:172)
        at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.processTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1187)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:929)
```

My classes can be found below:
**PreferenceClass.java**

```
package com.example.dentdevils.helper.retrofit.oauth2;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

public class PreferenceClass extends Application {

    public static final String PREFERENCE = "accessTokenPref";
    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    public PreferenceClass() {
        super();

    }

    public PreferenceClass(Context context) {
        sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    public String getToken() {
        String token = sharedPreferences.getString("token", "");
        return token;
    }

    public void setToken(String token) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString("token", token);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public void clearToken() {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.remove("token");
        editor.commit();
    }

}
```

**cCustomerService.java**

```
package com.example.dentdevils.helper.retrofit.oauth2.client;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

import com.example.dentdevils.helper.retrofit.oauth2.OauthConstant;
import com.example.dentdevils.helper.retrofit.oauth2.PreferenceClass;

import java.io.IOException;

import okhttp3.FormBody;
import okhttp3.Interceptor;
import okhttp3.MediaType;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.RequestBody;
import okhttp3.Response;
import okio.Buffer;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class cCustomerService {



    private static OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {

                private PreferenceClass preferenceClass;

                public PreferenceClass getPreferenceClass() {
                    return preferenceClass;
                }

                @Override
                public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                    Request request = chain.request();
                    Request.Builder requestBuilder = request.newBuilder();

                    RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
                            .add("access_token", getPreferenceClass().getToken())
                            .build();

                    String postBodyToString = bodyToString(request.body());
                    postBodyToString += ((postBodyToString.length() > 0) ? "&" : "") + bodyToString(formBody);
                    request = requestBuilder.post(RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"), postBodyToString))
                            .build();

                    return chain.proceed(request);
                }
            }).build();
    private static Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(OauthConstant.DATA_SERVER_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());
    public static Retrofit retrofit = builder.client(httpClient).build();

    public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass) {
        builder.client(httpClient).build();
        retrofit = builder.build();
        return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
    }

    public static String bodyToString(final RequestBody requestBody) {
        try {
            final RequestBody copy = requestBody;
            final Buffer buffer = new Buffer();
            if (copy != null) {
                copy.writeTo(buffer);
            } else {
                return "";
            }
            return buffer.readUtf8();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return "didn't work";
        }
    }

}
```

**MainActivity.java** - This is where I save the access_token

```
package com.example.dentdevils;

import android.Manifest;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.dentdevils.helper.retrofit.oauth2.PreferenceClass;
import com.example.dentdevils.helper.retrofit.oauth2.client.cOauthService;
import com.example.dentdevils.helper.retrofit.oauth2.request.AccessToken;
import com.example.dentdevils.helper.retrofit.oauth2.response.AccessTokenResponse;
import com.example.dentdevils.helper.retrofit.oauth2.service.OauthService;
import com.example.dentdevils.ui.HomeActivity;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA = 99;

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private Button btnLogin;
    private EditText inputEmail;
    private EditText inputPassword;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    private PreferenceClass preferenceClass;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        checkCameraPermission();
        preferenceClass = new PreferenceClass(this);

        inputEmail = findViewById(R.id.email);
        inputPassword = findViewById(R.id.txtEditPassword);
        btnLogin = findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);

        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(v -> getAccessToken());
    }

    public void getAccessToken() {
        progressDialog.show();
        AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken();
        accessToken.setClient_id("client");
        accessToken.setClient_secret("client");
        accessToken.setGrant_type("client_credentials");

        OauthService oauthService = cOauthService.createService(OauthService.class, inputEmail.getText().toString(), inputPassword.getText().toString());
        Call<AccessTokenResponse> call = oauthService.fetchAccessToken(accessToken);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<AccessTokenResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<AccessTokenResponse> call, retrofit2.Response<AccessTokenResponse> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    String a = response.body().getAccess_token();
                    preferenceClass.setToken(a);
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                } else {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "There was an error, please try again!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<AccessTokenResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("Error", t.getMessage());
            }
        });

    }

    public boolean checkCameraPermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setTitle("Permission Required!")
                        .setMessage("This app requires the camera permission to be able to capture images of car damage. Please grant the app access to the camera by going into your Settings > Apps > Apps > Dent Devils > Permissions > Camera, then press Allow.")
                        .setPositiveButton("", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA);
                            }
                        })
                        .create()
                        .show();
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA);
            }
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

**ViewCustomers.java** - This is where I try to access the token

```
package com.example.dentdevils;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.dentdevils.helper.retrofit.oauth2.PreferenceClass;
import com.example.dentdevils.helper.retrofit.oauth2.client.cCustomerService;
import com.example.dentdevils.helper.retrofit.oauth2.response.CustomerResponse;
import com.example.dentdevils.helper.retrofit.oauth2.service.CustomerService;

import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;



public class ViewCustomers extends AppCompatActivity {

    private PreferenceClass preferenceClass;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_customers);

        preferenceClass = new PreferenceClass(this);
        getAllCustomers();

    }

    public void getAllCustomers() {

        CustomerService customerService = cCustomerService.createService(CustomerService.class);
        Call<List<CustomerResponse>> callArray = customerService.getCustomers();
        callArray.enqueue(new Callback<List<CustomerResponse>>() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<CustomerResponse>> call, Response<List<CustomerResponse>> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(ViewCustomers.this, "Success!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//                    List<CustomerResponse> customers = response.body();
//                    customers.forEach(customer -> Log.d("CUSTOMERS", customer.getName()));
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(ViewCustomers.this, "There was an error, please try again!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<CustomerResponse>> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(ViewCustomers.this, "Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: why is your customerservice and preferenceClass having the same code

Comment: @aryanagarwal none of the code is the same? My cCustomerService class references the PreferenceClass

Comment: you have pasted your preference class twice and once under the name of customerservice please edit

Comment: @aryanagarwal ah that's what you meant! My mistake, I will edit now

Comment: private PreferenceClass preferenceClass(customerservice.java) ,  you have not  provided the context while creating the object

Comment: @aryanagarwal How would I do that? I tried to use context in an earlier version of the app but it also didn't work so I must have done it wrong

Comment: like this private `PreferenceClass preferenceClass = new PreferenceClass(this.getApplicationContext());` and also place `super()` inside `context` constructor

Comment: @aryanagarwal I get an error that states ```Cannot resolve method 'getApplicationContext()'```. I have added ```public PreferenceClass(Context context) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        //sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }``` to the PreferenceClass, is that correct?